# I have two vectors u and v. Can I find a quaternion and the quaternion axis if my rotation around this axis is 180 degrees?

Tags: vectors, quaternions, cross-product

I have the two vectors *v* and *u* as (1x3) matrices. I need to rotate vector *v* around an unknown axis to the point at vector *u*. My main question is, is there an axis that will satisfy this problem if *v* must rotate around the axis 180 degrees to meet *u*?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The axis should bisect the angle between $u$ and $v$. Obviously $u$ and $v$ must have the same length, so you can use the vector $(u+v)/2$ as an axis. This won't work if $v=-u$ but in that case any axis perpendicular to $u$ will work. Do you see why? You could (should?) add the fruits of your labor on this remark to the question body as additional context. That will improve the question (and helps answerers to figure out where exactly your problem is). See [our guide for new askers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/11619).

Comment: Yes this answers my question but just to clarify, this won't work for finding an axis if *v* is not equal to *u*, correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have the two vectors v and u as (1x3) matrices. I need to rotate vector v around an unknown axis to the point at vector u. My main question is, is there an axis that will satisfy this problem if v must rotate around the axis 180 degrees to meet u?

*I will take "meets" as overlapping...*

Yes! This axis almost always exists!

You can also easily calculate this axis with the formula for Quaternions and spatial rotation:
$$ v_{\text{rotaded}} = p \cdot v \cdot \overline{p} $$

$r$ is the rotation axis: $\frac{r}{|r|}$ is this rotation axis represented as an unit quaternion/unit vector.

You can calculate this unit quaternion as follows wiht $\theta$ as your rotation angle and $\frac{r}{|r|}$ as your "rotation axis":
$$ p = e^{\frac{\theta}{2} \cdot \frac{r}{|r|}} $$
$$ u = e^{\frac{\theta}{2} \cdot \frac{r}{|r|}} \cdot v \cdot e^{-\frac{\theta}{2} \cdot \frac{r}{|r|}} $$

If we say that your rotationangle is $180^{\circ} = \pi$ we can write this as:
$$ u = e^{\frac{\pi}{2} \cdot \frac{r}{|r|}} \cdot v \cdot e^{-\frac{\pi}{2} \cdot \frac{r}{|r|}} $$
$$ u = \left( \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right) + \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right) \cdot \frac{r}{|r|} \right) \cdot v \cdot \left( \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right) - \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right) \cdot \frac{r}{|r|} \right)$$
$$ u =  \frac{r}{|r|} \cdot v \cdot -\frac{r}{|r|}$$
And now you can solve this for $r$ and there is "always" a rotation axis for which this applies!

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, but just to understand fully how exactly would you then solve for the axis at that point? Obviously, u and v are already known, so would the rest just be solving for the rotation axis with the algebra of the two vectors? Given that, how can you divide two vectors? Would you use them in the complex number forms using *i , j , k*?

Comment: @IanHoldman Yes. You would just solve for the rotation axis, but solving it is a bit diffrent: Multiplication is usually used for this. If you want to divide by a vector $a$, multiply this vector $a^{-1}$. Then you have to decide whether to multiply left or right. if you do this, then you can calculate with the quaternions as if they were vectors. But I would usi the $\mathrm{i}$, $\mathrm{j}$, $\mathrm{k}$ form, since I could perhaps save myself some work with them. But if you just want to calculate the axis, you can leave it in vector form...

Comment: If multiplying vector *u* by vector *v*, would I simply use the (x,y,z) of the vectors and convert each into (xi+yj+zk) and multiply those together? Or use the Hamilton product of those two in *i , j , k* form to find the new vector?

Comment: Then to find the Hamilton product, what, if  anything, would I used as *a*? And then how would I remove the *^2* around the *r* and then solve for it?

Comment: @IanHoldman Yes you can use the Hamilton product. I think that you are looking at something too complex: you can calculate the ... to the power of 2 with plusminus the root of it and you can use the polar form for quaternions for this...
You can also reshape it more easily: If you calculate a pure quaternion a times a quaternion b, it's the same as: $a \cdot b = -b \cdot a$ With this follows: $u =   \frac{r}{|r|} \cdot -\frac{r}{|r|} \cdot -v = (\frac{r}{|r|})^{2} \cdot v$ aka $(\frac{r}{|r|})^{2}= u \cdot v^{-1}$ aka $\frac{r}{|r|}=\pm\sqrt{u \cdot v^{-1}}$...

Comment: @IanHoldman When you got $\frac{r}{|r|}=\pm\sqrt{u \cdot v^{-1}}$ there is $\frac{r}{|r|}=\operatorname{sign(r)}$ aka you cant directly solve for r but if you got $\frac{r}{|r|}$ then you can simply define an axis / function with the same orientation. This is your rotationaxis.

Comment: How would I go about finding the square root of a quaternion since it has multiple imaginary numbers? Any time I do I get stuck because every example only uses *i*.